# Ansible double loop with number increment

Tags: loops, ansible

I have the below ansible task which converts a .p12 certificate to a Java Keystore.
Currently I am looping over inventory hosts called "java" and also want to increment the cert_alias value for each loop (like 1, 2 etc) while looping over 'java' hosts.
I don't have experience in this double loop...could some one suggest how to achieve this.

```
- name: Import a pkcs12 Keystore with a specified alias, create it if it doesn't exist
  java_cert:
     pkcs12_path: {{item}}_cert.p12
     pkcs12_alias: test
     pkcs12_password: test@123
     cert_alias: 1 >>>>>>> Need this also to be looped
     keystore_path: tlsKeyStore
     keystore_type: "JKS"
     keystore_pass: test@123
     keystore_create: yes
  loop: "{{ query('inventory_hostnames', 'java') }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Q: *"**Increment the cert_alias value for each loop.**"*

A: Use [Extended loop variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables). For example, given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
[java]
srv1
srv2
srv3
```

The playbook

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "[{{ item }}] cert_alias: {{ ansible_loop.index }}"
      loop: "{{ query('inventory_hostnames', 'java') }}"
      loop_control:
        extended: true
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: '[srv1] cert_alias: 1'
  msg: '[srv2] cert_alias: 2'
  msg: '[srv3] cert_alias: 3'
```

Comment: Thanks alot...This has fixed my issue